# Req.params.id get overwritten by another value

Tags: node.js, regex, express, routes

Please help, I can't figure out why my my req.params.qcerrorId is being overwritten by app.js...I see both the id and app.js populate when I console.log. Code follows below. Thanks in advance.

```
//Show Single Route
router.get("/employee/:id/qcerror/:qcerrorId", isLoggedin, function(req, res){
    console.log(req.params['qcerrorId']);
    QcError.findById(req.params.qcerrorId, function(err, foundQcError){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
    res.render('qcerrors/show', {employee: req.params.id, qcerror: foundQcError});
        }
    });
});
```

Error with console.log on first 2 lines.

```
5ad924324d0db10fe02ab4ad
app.js
{ CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "app.js" at path "_id" for model "QcError"
    at MongooseError.CastError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:27:11)
    at ObjectId.cast (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:158:13)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:724:12)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1095:15)
    at ObjectId.castForQuery (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:198:15)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1064:15)
    at cast (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:300:32)
    at Query.cast (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3210:12)
    at Query._castConditions (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1280:10)
    at Query._findOne (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1496:8)
    at process.nextTick (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/kareem/index.js:311:33)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "app.js" at path "_id" for model "QcError"',
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: '"app.js"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'app.js',
```

It is returning "app.js" after the "qcerrorId", why?

Comment: Most probably this API is being called two times. First time you pass the correct Id and second time you passed something wrong

Comment: I see....but I still can't figure out why this is happening. Any way to accept only the first value?

Comment: how are you calling this API ?

Comment: Using an a tag...{<a href="/employee/<%= employee._id %>/qcerror/<%=qcerror._id%>">}....it routes correctly, and I see the page correctly, except I get  get that error and the page keeps loading.

Comment: @GabrielMotta BTW: Why is this tagged as regex? I cannot find any pattern in your question.

Comment: Sorry i thought this could potentially be solved by using regex. Anyways, this issue has been solved....I was  missing the address on my app.use("employee/:id/qcerrror", qcerrorRoute). Once I added that, the issue was solved.